# How can I enable JavaScript for 'packed chrome apps' such as Insomnia or Postman?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, whitelist

The Google results were atrocious for this specific issue, so I decided to create a Q&A here.

I have JavaScript disabled for all websites, and enabled through a whitelist of exceptions.

What do I add to allow Chrome apps/extensions to work?

`chrome-extension://` doesn't seem to work, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found through [this comment](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/712#issuecomment-75361332), you apparently add this to your whitelist (for Mac):
`file:///<user home directory>/Library/Application%20Support/Google/Chrome/<chrome profile>/Extensions/`